# Saving to a Word Document with bookmarks with data from a data set

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a program that I am trying to put the fields from the database into a Word Document that contains bookmarks. I can get it to work for one entry at a time but i am trying to get it to read a data set and place each row from the dataset on a new page using the document that contains the bookmarks. I am able to get it to place the content on the first page but when it reads the second row it replaces the content from the first row with that content. Is there a way to get it to create new page for each row using the document that has the bookmarks in it?

Below is the code I am currently using.

using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

```
    public static void printAll()
        {
            SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SQLiteDataAdapter da;
            DataSet ds;

            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

            //Start Word and open a document.
            Word._Application oWord;
            Word._Document oDoc;
            oWord = new Word.Application();
            oWord.Visible = true;
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Recipe.docx"));
            Word.Range wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
            string Title = null;
            string Author;
            string Type;
            string Recipe;


            string query = "SELECT RecipeID, Type, Name, Author, Recipe FROM Recipes";
            da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, con);

            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Recipes");

            for (int y = 0; y < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; y++)
            {
                Title = ds.Tables[0].Rows[y]["Name"].ToString();
                Author = ds.Tables[0].Rows[y]["Author"].ToString();
                Type = ds.Tables[0].Rows[y]["Type"].ToString();
                Recipe = Dangl.TextConverter.Rtf.RtfToText.ConvertRtfToText(ds.Tables[0].Rows[y]["Recipe"].ToString());


                //Inserts title string into title bookmark in word document
                Dictionary<string, string> titleBold = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Title", Title } };

                foreach (var bookmark in titleBold)
                {
                    Word.Bookmark bm = oDoc.Bookmarks[bookmark.Key];
                    Word.Range range = bm.Range;
                    range.Text = bookmark.Value;
                    range.Font.Bold = 5;
                    oDoc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark.Key, range);

                }

                // Inserts author, type and recipe into corosponding bookmarks in word document
                Dictionary<string, string> bookmarks = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Author", Author }, { "Type", Type }, { "Recipe", Recipe } };

                foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
                {
                    Word.Bookmark bm = oDoc.Bookmarks[bookmark.Key];
                    Word.Range range = bm.Range;
                    range.Text = bookmark.Value;
                    range.Font.Bold = 0;
                    oDoc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark.Key, range);

                }


                    object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;

                    oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
                    object oPageBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;

                wrdRng.InsertBreak(ref oPageBreak);
                    wrdRng.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
                    wrdRng.InsertAfter(Title);
                    wrdRng.InsertParagraphAfter();


            }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

**Update**
I have gotten it working with the help of Cindy Meister's answer.
I am now able to get the book marks to be each entry in the dataset by using the Building Blocks. 
I have now added the ability to have each data set entry on its own page. I am still working on getting it to not print a blank page with the building block in it at the end.

Below is the working code for anyone who might be looking for this solution.

```
        public static void printAll()
    {
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SQLiteDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;

        object oMissing = Missing.Value;
        object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

        //Start Word and open a document.
        Word._Application oWord;
        Word._Document oDoc;
        oWord = new Word.Application();
        oWord.Visible = true;
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Recipe.dotx"));
        Word.Range wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
        string Title;
        string Author;
        string Type;
        string Recipe;



        string query = "SELECT RecipeID, Type, Name, Author, Recipe FROM Recipes";
        da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, con);

        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Recipes");

        for (int y = 0; y < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; y++)
        {
            Title = ds.Tables[0].Rows[y]["Name"].ToString();
            Author = ds.Tables[0].Rows[y]["Author"].ToString();
            Type = ds.Tables[0].Rows[y]["Type"].ToString();
            Recipe = Dangl.TextConverter.Rtf.RtfToText.ConvertRtfToText(ds.Tables[0].Rows[y]["Recipe"].ToString());


            //Inserts title string into title bookmark in word document
            Dictionary<string, string> titleBold = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Title", Title } };

            foreach (var bookmark in titleBold)
            {
                Word.Bookmark bm = oDoc.Bookmarks[bookmark.Key];
                Word.Range range = bm.Range;
                range.Text = bookmark.Value;
                range.Font.Bold = 5;
                oDoc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark.Key, range);

            }

            // Inserts author, type and recipe into corosponding bookmarks in word document
            Dictionary<string, string> bookmarks = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Author", Author }, { "Type", Type }, { "Recipe", Recipe } };

            foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
            {
                Word.Bookmark bm = oDoc.Bookmarks[bookmark.Key];
                Word.Range range = bm.Range;
                range.Text = bookmark.Value;
                range.Font.Bold = 0;
                oDoc.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark.Key, range);


            }


            object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;

            oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

           wrdRng.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);

            Object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Object objBreak = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;
            Object objUnit = Word.WdUnits.wdStory;

            oWord.Selection.EndKey(ref objUnit, ref nullobj);
            oWord.Selection.InsertBreak(ref objBreak);


            oWord.NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Item("BuildingBlockBookmarks").Insert(oDoc.Characters.Last, true);


        }




    }
```

Comment: The issue is that you're only creating one document, therefor each time you assign a value to the bookmark the bookmark gets a new value, you need a new bookmark for each new value. Are you wanting collection of word docs each with a recipe on it or are you wanting one "multi-page" doc with a recipe on each page? If you move the call to create a new doc inside the for loop you'll get a doc for each title but if you don't use a template you'll get an error as the original doc is locked for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use Building Blocks to insert "boiler-plate text". A Building Block can contain pretty much everything.

Inserting a Building Block with bookmarks will remove any bookmarks "with the same name" earlier in the document. This means that, after the bookmarks have been filled for the first row of data, insert the Building Block and the next row of data will go into this set of bookmarks. And so on.

1. Open the document for editing.
2. Select the section of text that should be repeated (including the bookmarks).
3. Go to Insert/Text/Quick Parts and select `Save Selection to Quick Part Gallery`. Enter the information for Name, Category, Gallery, etc. in the dialog box. This creates a Building Block.
4. Building Blocks must be saved in a *template* file (dotx or dotm). In a default installation this can be Normal.dotm or the Building Blocks.dotx. It's also possible to use a "custom template", supplied as part of your project.

The following code sample demonstrates how a Building Block named `BB with bookmarks` stored in Normal.dotm can be inserted at the end of a document.

```
oWord.NormalTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries.Item("BB with bookmarks").Insert(oDoc.Characters.Last, true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This did exactly what i was looking for. You are a life saver.